# Popup calender appers big primefaces 4.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

[image: p:calender appears big]
I am using  PF4 and the calender appears to be big.
How to overcome the problem.

Comment: Have you modified your `theme.css`? Did you specify any custom CSS in your website? If so, provide the code.

Comment: Thanks @manuel i managed to get it work in the given time I have used custom css and manipulated it and things work fine ...